# MySQL/PHP Count

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 MySQL tables, one for storing albums and the other for songs. I am displaying a list of albums in a table, and I want to be able to add a column called `songs` to display the number of songs in this album. The way I have it now just messes up my table:

Thanks for everyone's help!

Comment: what makes you to not write code ?

Comment: Could you please put the code in, instead of a screenshot of the highlighted code?

Comment: Can you show some rendered HTML?

Comment: Why do you want to see HTML when the question is about MySQL?

Comment: @JezenThomas: Because the table is being messed up? (HTML `<table>` is also a context here)

Comment: What is wrong with your current query? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Can you show the code that fills `$rs`, please?

Comment: if(!$rs = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $ws_table")) {
   echo "Cannot select table";
  }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that "playlist" is what you consider an album and the first `while` loop iterates on playlists, I'd rewrite your code like this:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {
    echo "<tr>\n";
    echo "<td>".$row['playlist_id']."</td>";

    // Assuming playlist_id is an integer value in your database
    $query = "
        SELECT Playlist_id, COUNT(Playlist_id) AS songCount
        FROM ws_music 
        WHERE Playlist_id = ". intval ($row['playlist_id']) ."
        GROUP BY Playlist_id 
    ";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    // No need for the second while loop
    $row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    echo "<td>There are ". $row2['songCount'] ." ". $row2['Playlist_id'] ." song.</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```